# Why I can't import beautifulsoup on mac using python 2.7 after installing it by using pip and/or easy_install?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, pip, easy-install

```
$ sudo pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

I installed `beautifulsoup4` and it seems to be successfully completed but I can't import it:

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import beautifulsoup4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named beautifulsoup4
>>> import beautifulsoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named beautifulsoup
```

Comment: Read your documentation: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ which tells you to use 'bs4'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module is called `bs4`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```