# sklearn isn't there but it is up-to-date in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, scikit-learn

On the server of my firm I tried to run a Python script. Yet it told me that sklearn was missing but it is up-to-date in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

```
:~/Eclipse-Stats$ python Main.py
2017-07-24 14:01:55.852751
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import kmeans
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eclipse-Stats/kmeans.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sklearn
ImportError: No module named sklearn
:~/Eclipse-Stats$ pip install -U scikit-learn
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Maybe it thinks it isn't on the server but when I try to install it, it installs it on my laptop which already have it ?

I have Python 2.7.13 installed on the server. It seems it is the problem as far as when I run wiyt `python3` it seems to work :

```
 ~/Eclipse-Stats$ python3 Main.py
  File "Main.py", line 113
    print "list of groups you can recommend : "
                                              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

#### From Python interpreter

But a Python Specialist on the Spanish version of the site (FJSevilla) told me it wasn't sure.

I tried to import it from the python interpreter :

```
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

So I tried to uninstall, purge and reinstall it (I don't remeber where but I think on the prompt):

#### Uninstall and reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3-base
...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Then I tried to import it again but it failed :

```
>>> import kmeans
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "kmeans.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sklearn
ImportError: No module named sklearn
>>> kmeans.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'kmeans' is not defined
```

And with :

```
>>>sudo pip install -U scikit-learn

>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

#### A permission issue ?

My last attempts were to grant permissions issue according to [this answer from boshea in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796013/8081296)

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-41-89:~/Eclipse-Stats$ sudo chmod -R go+rX /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
ubuntu@ip-172-31-41-89:~/Eclipse-Stats$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 24 2017, 09:52:34)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

#### At the system level

FJSevilla proposed to do look if sklearn was already installed at the system level :

```
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

#### Anyway ...

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn
__check_build              exceptions.pyc            multiclass.py
__init__.py                externals                 multiclass.pyc
__init__.pyc               feature_extraction        multioutput.py
_build_utils               feature_selection         multioutput.pyc
_isotonic.so               gaussian_process          naive_bayes.py
base.py                    grid_search.py            naive_bayes.pyc
base.pyc                   grid_search.pyc           neighbors
```

It seems that the installation was okay but the interpreter doesn't look into the right folder ...

Comment: Are you sure that the default python command on server goes to python2 and not python3?

Comment: @VivekKumar
`$ python -V
Python 2.7.13`

Comment: @jezrael, hello, I'm so sorry to disturb you but I'm so stuck with this issue since one day. Would you have any idea ?