# Unable to install new packages for Python 2.7 Mac Terminal

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I have installed Python 2.7 on my Mac, but I am unable to install packages using pip2.7 install. Any time I try to install a package in the terminal, for example,

```
pip2.7 install pandas
```

I get the OSError:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
```

I also have Python 3.6 installed and I am able to install packages for that version, but I have some work that needs to be done in 2.7 and I want to be able to run my script and ensure that it works in 2.7.

Comment: `sudo pip2.7 install pandas`?

Comment: That common doesn't throw an error, but when I try to import pandas in a python shell, it says that the module cannot be found .

Comment: Did you invoke python2.7?

Comment: When I am in the shell, sys.verison returns 2.7.12.

Comment: Restart your shell and try again, or open a new terminal.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location) fixed the import issue, not sure why but I can import pandas now...

Comment: Great, thanks for the link. I've closed as a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 0):

you can't change thing in /system on mac and the default python‘s library of mac is here. So you can't install anything.

The best way is install a new python of 2.7

The another way is [close the rootless of mac](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-turn-off-mac-os-x-system-integrity-protection-rootless-3638975/).

Comment: Are you serious? You want to open OP's computer to security threats through mis-information?

Comment: I'm sorry for what 's the "OP"meaning?  I have four version of python on mac, installing multi-version  maybe a good way.

Comment: Original Poster