# Messed up pip environment and unable to python import modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

My python related versions and paths are as follows

```
pip -V
```

output

```
pip 19.1.1 from /home/USER_NAME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

```
which pip
```

output

```
/home/USER_NAME/.local/bin/pip
```

```
python -V
```

output

```
Python 3.6.7
```

```
which python
```

output

```
/home/USER_NAME/bin/python
```

The problem is I used several methods to update pip and everything messed up. So now I can use python modules even though they are installed using pip. Example

```
pip install requests
```

says

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.18.4)
```

but when I import requests in python code I get this

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests
```

The reason is that pip links to `.local` directory how to resolve this I tried uninstalling pip and reinstalling but didn't help. Help is appreciated

Comment: did you have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796013/8954691)

Comment: you may have two pythons installed and `pip` may install in different Python then you run. Check if you have `.local/bin/python`. You should have also `pip3` and `pip3.6` which may install in correct Python. Or you may use `python -m pip install requests`. It may need to use `sudo` to install in global folder instead of `.local` directory.

Comment: @furas when I use sudo the default python and pip is python 2.7. So no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though which python shows 
`/home/USER_NAME/bin/python` because it is symlinked to the global scope python which is in `/usr/bin/`
But the pip is installed in the local scope of the user (/home/$USER/.local/bin/). So when you run

`pip install requests` It checks for `/home/$USER/.local` so the requirement satisfies.

The solution is, both pip and python should be in the same scope (either in global or the user's)

You can uninstall your local pip (`pip uninstall pip`) and use global pip and global scope python

OR

You can symlink `/home/$USER/bin/python` to local user scope python (`ln -s /home/$USER/.local/bin/python3 /home/$user/bin/python`) after removing the current symlink in `$HOME/bin/python`

Comment: `pip uninstall pip` worked and yes just removing old symlink resolved the python too. Thanks a lot