# Smartsheet API - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: smartsheet-api

I have been battling this for a few hours now.  Trying to use smartsheet-python-sdk on my new laptop.  The script I have works perfectly on my old laptop.  I am on OS X.   Both are running Python 3.7.4 and I have been through pip list on both and have same versions of other modules.   Nothing I do on the new laptop allows me to execute my script.   As I say, works perfectly on my old laptop so has to be something environmental.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot further?

```py
import os
import sys
import urllib
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import smartsheet

import logging
from shared import shared
```

```sh
(sc) kgeorgeson@kgeorgeson-a02 eda-ps-forecasts % python --version
Python 3.7.4
```

```sh
(sc) kgeorgeson@kgeorgeson-a02 eda-ps-forecasts % pip list
Package               Version
--------------------- ----------
appdirs               1.4.3
bitarray              1.0.1
certifi               2019.11.28
chardet               3.0.4
idna                  2.8
impyla                0.15.0
numpy                 1.17.3
packaging             20.1
pandas                0.25.3
pip                   20.0.2
ply                   3.11
pyparsing             2.4.6
python-dateutil       2.8.0
pytz                  2019.3
requests              2.21.0
requests-toolbelt     0.9.1
setuptools            34.3.2
six                   1.10.0
smartsheet-python-sdk 2.86.0
thrift                0.9.3
thriftpy2             0.4.0
urllib3               1.24.1
```

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oabj8.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pip install module is not found. How to link python to pip location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, found out python being called was not using the virtual environment python, and instead using the local bin version. Therefore wasn't seeing the module in the virtual environment