# no module found "kivy" despite being installed

Tags: python, pip, kivy

Today my setup has given me a curveball:

```
(android) mark@python:~/frontend_android$ pip3 freeze
appdirs==1.4.4
buildozer==1.2.0
certifi==2020.11.8
chardet==3.0.4
Cython==0.29.21
distlib==0.3.1
docutils==0.16
filelock==3.0.12
idna==2.10
imutils==0.5.3
Kivy==2.0.0rc4
Kivy-Garden==0.1.4
numpy==1.19.4
opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46
pexpect==4.8.0
Pillow==8.0.0
plyer==1.4.3
ptyprocess==0.6.0
Pygments==2.7.2
pytesseract==0.3.6
requests==2.24.0
sh==1.14.1
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.25.11
virtualenv==20.1.0
(android) mark@python:~/frontend_android$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import kivy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

How can this be, given I've got only Python 3.8.5 running on my system and latest pip ?

Comment: Do `python -m pip freeze` and see if `kivy` is installed. When you do `python -m pip ...` you call the `pip` is actually the one that `python` is associated to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pip install module is not found. How to link python to pip location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi  `python -m pip freeze` gave me different list of packages. One without Kivy and other packages.

Comment: Then you have two `python` installed on your computer, and `pip3` points to the wrong one. See the answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

a lot of people have this problem, one solution I found that worked for many people is to install it straight from wheel.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv
```

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with installing straight from the wheel and more to do with calling `pip` as `python -m pip`

Comment: Well, I reinstalled pip with the `get-pip.py` script which includes everything.