# no module pip found Spyder

Tags: python, module, pip, spyder

I'm desperate, I have installed Spyder on Windows 10, but pip won't work. Anytime I run

> pip install package

I get no module pip found. If I try with conda then I get:

> The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.  Please use `%pip install` instead.

To which I try

> %pip install

Thus still obtaining no module pip found. Honestly I have no idea how to proceed. I have anaconda installed as well, which actually tells me pip is indeed installed, but nontheless I can't use it.

Yes, pip is upgraded to the last version.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location

Make sure you put what OS your using. What is your current python path?

Comment: they are nowhere similar. Besides, I'm a noob asking for help, why is everybody being je*ks.

Comment: I'm trying to help you out brother. IDK who voted down

Comment: I just edited the text. I'm using Windows 10, please ask me anything you need to know.

Comment: what's your path. You can normally just start python, `import sys` and then type `sys.executable`

Comment: C:\\Users\\utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\python.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it seems like your python path is not correct. You can't find pip because it's not installed there (it may be in your path, but if not, you will need to add the python `\Scripts` to your path. *Generally*, you should keep python in the standard path that it installs to. Below are some simple instructions to add python to your path in windows. Follow [this tutorial](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/4) to add your `\Scripts` path as well (although it's pretty much the same process).

To add the path to the python.exe file to the Path variable, start the Run box and enter sysdm.cpl:

[image]

This should open up the System Properties window. Go to the Advanced tab and click the Environment Variables button:

[image]

In the System variable window, find the Path variable and click Edit:

[image]

Position your cursor at the end of the Variable value line and add the path to the python.exe file, preceded with the semicolon character (;). So in the example below, if your python path is at the root of C:\ you would add the following value:

`;C:\Python3`

Comment: Thank you kindly for the time you spent and the help you gave me.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I did add the path to the Value as you wrote but the error is still the same. I followed also the guide, so I checked via CMD. Once I got the command 'python' working, the next part: "python -m pip install -U pip" gave me once again the same issue: no module named pip.

Comment: That’s unfortunate. I don’t know too much more for Windows. Maybe just try a fresh install and leave everything default for install locations