# Python Selenium Module Not Found

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I was trying to use selenium in a short program but it keeps giving me this error. I've tried everything - I've even tried uninstalling and reinstalling it so many times, yet it keeps saying that the module doesn't exist.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`

As I mentioned earlier, I uninstalled and reinstalled selenium, but then it always says this:

`Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from selenium) (1.26.4)`

I've tried every single solution that I've read online, but it still won't work. Please help me so that I can finally work on this project.

Comment: Do you know if there is any virtual environment that could be involved? `venv`, `conda`, or perhaps different Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove selenium library again and write this command :

```
python3 -m pip install -U selenium
```

Sometimes python make an errors like this because of old version of python's.

Comment: I tried that but it still won't work. It keeps taking the file from the cache and then saying it doesn't exist when I try to run my program.

Comment: Probably your problem's solution in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location       Because "local" path in your terminal exists message