# No module named 'speech_recognition'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed a wsl2 kernel on Windows and pip installed SpeechRecognition, its the latest update as is python but it keeps telling me 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'.

`import speech_recognition as sr`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you have other versions of python installed and the command line uses `pip` from one of those. You could search your file system for all the different installations of python.

Comment: @quamrana How do I do that?

Comment: Search for `pip.exe`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pip install module is not found. How to link python to pip location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location)

Answer (score 0):

If the module is not found then perhaps it was not installed correctly. How did you install SpeechRecognition?

Instead of `pip` though, you could try `pip3` installing:

```
pip3 install --upgrade speechrecognition
```

For Jupyter notebook however, I have had to use:

```
!pip3 install --upgrade speechrecognition
```

then you can import as required and check the version:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
sr.__version__
```

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper Good point. I have edited my answer to remove the `sudo` install recommendation.