# why the python module did not found but install tell me already required

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am using this command to install Python module:

```
~/source/pydolphin on  master! ⌚ 23:57:49
$ pip3 install -r requirements-pip.txt|grep celery                                                                                               ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Collecting celery==5.1.2
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/06/9d/61976ecc8caf0a03357bd174fa23c43b9dcd85f4c9667aa692de361cae84/celery-5.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (401 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8.0,>=7.0 in /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from celery==5.1.2->-r requirements-pip.txt (line 13)) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit in /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from click-repl>=0.1.6->celery==5.1.2->-r requirements-pip.txt (line 13)) (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from kombu<6.0,>=5.1.0->celery==5.1.2->-r requirements-pip.txt (line 13)) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit->click-repl>=0.1.6->celery==5.1.2->-r requirements-pip.txt (line 13)) (0.2.5)
Installing collected packages: croniter, opencv-python, coverage, args, clint, mamba, click-didyoumean, click-repl, vine, click-plugins, amqp, kombu, billiard, celery, lxml, cssselect, itemadapter, w3lib, parsel, jmespath, itemloaders, queuelib, hpack, hyperframe, h2, PyDispatcher, protego, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, service-identity, constantly, incremental, Automat, hyperlink, priority, Twisted, scrapy, apollo-client, jsonpickle
```

the module is installed. but when I show the module like this:

```
~/source/pydolphin on  master! ⌚ 23:56:06
$ pip3 show celery                                                                                                                               ‹ruby-2.7.2›
WARNING: Package(s) not found: celery
```

tell me the module did not found, why pip3 tell me module already required? and the pip3 did not use anaconda3 module. If did not use anaconda3 module, the pip3 should use it's own module cache!!!!

Comment: What's the full output of `pip3 install -r requirements-pip.txt`? I don't see any confirmation that installation was successful (though I'm not a pip expert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me once when I downloaded numpy using pip, but I used a computer with windows, and the solution was to move a file from one folder to another.
The solution might be different on a Linux pc. Maybe this post can help you:
[Python pip install module is not found. How to link python to pip location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location)