# No module named 'pyrebase'

Tags: python, pyrebase

I cannot seem to get pyrebase to import, despite it being installed. I have ran this:

> pip3 install pyrebase4

and it successfully installed, upon doing pip freeze I can see:

> Pyrebase4==4.50

However, when I try import it using

```
import pyrebase
```

it just spits out the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrebase'

I'm at a loss and have no idea what to do

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location helps you?

Comment: Not particularly. I can see it's installed, and I've checked it's install location, it's the same as all my other modules (which are running)