# No module named dbus - I already have that - Raspbian

Tags: python, linux, raspbian, dbus, raspberry-pi4

I'm getting an ImportError "no module named dbus" when I reinstalled it

> ("sudo apt-get install --reinstall dbus")

It wrote me

> "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 15 not
> upgraded"

Can anyone help me? I'm trying to use this github repository: ["keyboard_mouse_emulate_on_raspberry"](https://github.com/quangthanh010290/keyboard_mouse_emulate_on_raspberry#step-1-setup)

I need to fix that because of send_string.py file is giving me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_string.py", in line 4, in <module>
    import dbus
```

Comment: The issues with `dbus` not being available in Python on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi OS) is if you are using the `lite` version or have a Python Virtual Environment. I also think the package to install is `sudo apt-get install python3-dbus`.  A simpler test would be do the following on the command line `python3 -c "import dbus; print(dbus.__file__)"` and update your question with what that returns. For me it reports `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

Use pip, not apt-get.

```
pip install dbus
```

or

```
python pip install dbus
```

or

```
python -m pip install dbus
```

Comment: executing "pip3 --version" is giving me "pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9), on pip install dbus is giving me "No matching distribution found for dbus", python pip install dbus is giving me "python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory", python -m pip install dbus is giving me "/usr/bin/python: No module named pip"

Comment: Try python -m pip install dbus

Comment: "/usr/bin/python: No module named pip", I've already installed him (and reinstalled 2 times)

Comment: Try python3 -m pip install dbus

Comment: same error, now I tried to change dbus for dbus-python, it's already installed, may I edit the file calling dbus?

Comment: try installing dbus-next, it appears that's a more updated version.

Comment: Sucessfully installed, but still getting error when I try to run send_string.py "string", still line 4

Comment: What is send_string.py?

Comment: its file from repository that i linked in post, error is in line 4 (import dbus), when i change it to (import dbus-next), there is error "import dbus-next" pointing to "-" with "invalid syntax" when i use space, same problem, when I use "_", "no moudel named dbus_next"

Comment: Did you try it with import dbus, not dbus-next?

Comment: yes, "no module named dbus"

Comment: Oh! you have to do import dbus_next, you can't use '-' in an import statement.

Comment: yes, I've did, still getting a error in line 4, "import dbus_next" "ImportError: No module named dbus_next"

Comment: The answer here should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location

Comment: I've tried, now when I run "echo $PYTHONPATH", it show me correctly ":usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages", but I'm still getting an ImportError "No module named dbus_next", I'm more confused than I was :D

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-dbus

Comment: "0 upgraded, 0newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded."

Comment: Huh. I am at a loss.

Comment: Me too, I'm so confused but I need to do it to work. If I don't have to do that, I had already deleted it all :D, thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: Maybe open an issue on github in that repository