# How can I resolve ModuleNotFoundError when importing accelerate despite it being listed under 'pip3 list'?

Tags: pip, accelerate

I have done pip3 install accelerate
pip3 list shows:
accelerate               0.19.0
certifi                  2023.5.7
charset-normalizer       3.1.0
cmake                    3.26.3
filelock                 3.12.0
idna                     3.4
Jinja2                   3.1.2
lit                      16.0.5
MarkupSafe               2.1.2
mpmath                   1.3.0
....

And yet when i use
from accelerate import Accelerator

I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accelerate'

Tried pip3 uninstall and reintall.
All this is on a virtual environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pip install module is not found. How to link python to pip location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location)